# NullPointerException when enabling/disabling scanner from barcode data input handler

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, barcode-scanner, windows-mobile-6

I'm developing for a Motorola barcode scanner and it seems I'm having some threading issue. When I set `barcode_OnRead()` as a handler for input from the scanner and manipulate the state of the scanner in the same flow, I get a `NullPointerException` soon after. For instance this will cause the issue:

```
private void barcode_OnRead(object sender, Symbol.Barcode.ReaderData readerData)
{
  this.barcode.EnableScanner = false;
}
```

It seems to me like a threading issue, but I'm not very proficient in C# and I don't know how to run sth on a different thread (the UI thread for instance)?

**Edit:** 
The code above alone will trigger the problem. `this.barcode` is not `null` at the time.
The stack trace from the exception:

```
at Barcode.Barcode.SetScanParameters()
at Barcode.Barcode.Reader_ReadNotify(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.TASK.Invoke()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control._InvokeAll()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
at Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop(IntPtr hwnMain)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form fm)
at AppName.Program.Main()
```

Comment: Can you show a bit more code? I assume you mean this.barcode becomes null (can you confirm?) this would suggests something is setting this elsewhere so it would be good to see more of the code.

Comment: No, I do not Thing this is a threading problem NullPointerException can you please post more code.

Comment: This code is all that's needed to trigger the problem. Plz see my edit.

Comment: Looks like you have a reference to the barcode reader in the UI or try to update a control from a background thread. Please read about background threads and delegates and event handlers on how to update UI from background thread. Without seeing more code, especially the UI one there is no more help.